# how to escape < > in string passed as parameters to java -jar?

Tags: java, jar, parameter-passing

I have a string which contains < and >. This string is passed as parameter to a jar.
But when the jar file is executed, I get an error saying system cannot find the specified file.

```
java -jar -Dparam=<par>whatever</par> c:\myjar.jar
```

How can I escape these special characters to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your path being `C:\` I'm assuming you're running Windows. If putting it in double quotes doesn't work, you can try using `^` as it is command prompt's escape character.

```
java -jar -Dparam=^<par^>whatever^</par^> c:\myjar.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows, try using double quotes.

Either `"java -jar -Dparam=<par>whatever</par> c:\myjar.jar"` or `java "-jar -Dparam=<par>whatever</par> c:\myjar.jar"` should do it.

If you use < or > on the windows command line, they perform the special function of redirecting the output.